# How to make loading screen on connecting sql database in java

Tags: java, sql-server, swing

I want to know if there is any way to make jLabel(as a loading icon) visible whenever connecting to sql through odbc in java.
Like when I click to add Data, it takes 5 Seconds to insert into database.So I want to make jlabel appear for 5 seconds and disappear when data inserted.

Comment: Perhaps you should figure out why it takes 5 seconds for an insert. Unless this is inserting a LOT of data that amount of time is way too long for an insert.

Comment: yes you are right.....I must figure out. but the main problem is the steps involved in inserting data. Like Make Drive, make Conection, create Statement.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long running tasks should be executed in a separate Thread so you don't prevent the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` from responding to events and painting the GUI.

So you could use a `SwingWorker`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and examples.

You may want to use a `JProgressBar` for this. Read the section on [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) for examples.

You could also use a `GlassPane` to display a message/icon. Check out [Disabled Glass Pane](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/disabled-glass-pane/) for an example.

Comment: ok any other suggestion.... really want to make loading icon appear and disappear.

Comment: bro thaks i got it. I must try to make it faster instead of making loading screen....LOL

Comment: But if I really want to do that, then your provided info is enough.